# create entities from interfaces

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a bunch of interfaces from which I want to create entities for typeorm.
Example interface file (shortened)

```
interface Tower {
    first: boolean;
    kills: number;
}
interface Objectives {
    baron: Baron;
    champion: Champion;
    dragon: Dragon;
    inhibitor: Inhibitor;
    riftHerald: RiftHerald;
    tower: Tower;
}
interface Team {
    bans: Ban[];
    objectives: Objectives;
    teamId: number;
    win: boolean;
}
interface Info {
    gameCreation: number;
    gameDuration: number;
    gameId: number;
    gameMode: string;
    gameName: string;
    gameStartTimestamp: number;
    gameType: string;
    gameVersion: string;
    mapId: number;
    participants: Participant[];
    platformId: string;
    queueId: number;
    teams: Team[];
    tournamentCode: string;
}
export interface MatchDTO {
    metadata: Metadata;
    info: Info;
}
```

How can I, based on these interfaces, create the enteties needed for typeorm using the typeorm cli?

Comment: You cannot. Classes are values and you can create types from values but not values from types.